# Is there a name for a matrix with symmetric but inverse entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix $A$ is symmetric if it is equal to its transpose. Then, the following equality holds between the entries of this matrix:
$$a_{ij}=a_{ji}$$
Is there an established name for a similar matrix in which we have instead the following equalities:
$$a_{ij}=a_{ji}^{-1}$$? (the entries are real numbers. ie the numbers in each pair are mutual multiplicative inverses)

**Context:** This matrix comes up when I put a general equilibrium of exchange values of goods in an economy into matrix form, with each row representing a different numéraire.

Comment: If you take the logarithm of all the entries, you get an antisymmetric matrix. But that's the best I can do.

Comment: @Arthur Interesting, I didn't think of that. Since $exp:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+\setminus \{0\}$ and $ln:\mathbb R^+\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R^+$ are invertible, and the exchange values are always positive, could you elaborate a bit about what operations (like matrix addition/multiplication/Lie bracket) one could do with antisymmetric matrices obtained via $ln$ and still be able to uniquely recover the underlying 'unnamed' matrices after applying the operations? That would pretty much answer how we can manipulate the 'unnamed' matrices.

Comment: And of course I wasn’t supposed to add the $+$ sign on the domain of $exp$ and codomain of $ln$...

Comment: In the [analytic hierarchy process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_hierarchy_process), a positive matrix with this property is called _pairwise comparison matrix_.

Comment: You could call it the transposed Hadamard inverse.  A similar, though not identical concept is the [relative gain array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_Gain_Array) from control theory.